# how to create a custom array adapter in android studio to disable clicks on list view item

Tags: android

current Uni student and i am trying to create a custom array adapter class that extends the ArrayAdapter class so i can disable clicks on selected items in the list view.

I am unsure how to implement this new class
this is what i have so far

```
package com.example.assignment1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public customAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
       // return super.isEnabled(position);
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to write the isEnabled function as well:

this is how i intend to use this function

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                poss = position + 1;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewFriends.this);
                builder.setTitle("Notice");
                builder.setMessage("Please select to to edit, delete a friend or cancel");

                // add the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                         //System.out.println(poss);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editOrDelete.class);
                        ArrayList<String> result1 = mydb.retrieveRow(poss);
                        name = result1.get(1);
                        age = result1.get(2);
                        gender = result1.get(3);
                        address = result1.get(4);
                        code = result1.get(0);
                        intent.putExtra("code", code);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("age", age);
                        intent.putExtra("gender", gender);
                        intent.putExtra("address", address);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNeutralButton(" Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        System.out.println(poss);
                        mydb.updateDeleted(poss);
                       if(listView.getChildAt(position).isEnabled())
                        {
                           listView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
                          // function to disable clicks
                       }
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();


            }
        });



    }
public void displayFriendList() {
        ArrayList<String> result = mydb.retrieveRows();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

so when the user clicks the delete button from the alert i would like to grey out the item they clicked on in the list view (i managed to achieve this) but i would also like for it not to be able to be clicked on once it has been deleted

and suggestions on how i can achieve this?

Comment: Check the answer below you'll come to know how to manage list items. Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Instead of using a regular `ListView` use a custom one:**

**1) Create a `CustomListView` class:**

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView{

//add these three constructors
public CustomListView(Context context){
super(context);
}
public CustomListView(Context context , AttributeSet attrs){
super(context , attrs);
}
public CustomListView(Context context , AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
super(context , attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

//handle the item click
@Override
public boolean performItemClick(View view , int position , long id){

if(!view.isEnabled()){
//don't handle the click
return false;
}else{
//handle the click
return super.performItemClick(view, position, id);
}

}

}
```

1. add the `CustomListView` that you created to your xml layout instead of `ListView`.
2. replace:

   ```
   ListView listView = findViewById(.......);
   ```

   by:

   ```
   CustomListView listView = findViewById(.......);
   ```

**2) remove these methods from your `CustomAdapter` class:**

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   // return super.isEnabled(position);
}
```

**3) handle the item click like that:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {

poss = position + 1;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewFriends.this);
builder.setTitle("Notice");
builder.setMessage("Please select to to edit, delete a friend or cancel");

// add the buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//.......keep whatever you have the same here

}
});

builder.setNeutralButton(" Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//disable the view so that you won't receive clicks again
view.setEnabled(false);

}
});

builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

}
});
```

If you use the above implementation, then when you click delete button in alert dialog the item won't receive the click event the next time.

Comment: thanks for this, it worked correctly, just had to change view.setEnabled to listView... 

not sure if this can be answered here or if ill need to ask a new question but ever time i click out of the page and go back into it, the deleted options go back to normal. is there a way to keep it deleted

Comment: 1) I don't know what you mean by "just had to change view.setEnabled to listView.". 2) For your second question, I can give you a hint about how to go about it, you will need to use a local database like `SharedPrefrences` to save the enabled state of each view which is a boolean (true or false) for each position. But that is out of the scope of your question you will have to ask a new question.

Comment: i just noticed that this will disable the whole list , whereas i needed to only disable the list item that was deleted

Comment: I tested the code and it worked for me. Did you follow the exact steps?

Comment: You told me you changed "view.setEnabled to listView", you must not change anything in the steps that I told you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which will help your case exactly and you'll come to know how to work with model in case you need to perform anything on the list item.

**CustomAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();

    CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<DataModel > data) {
        super(context, resource,data);
       dataModels=data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if(dataModels.size()>0) {
            DataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(position);
            return dataModel.isEnabled();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**DataModel**

```
public class DataModel {

    private String data;

    private boolean isEnabled=true;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    CustomAdapter adapter;

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels =new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
         displayFriendList();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Notice");
                builder.setMessage("Please select to to edit, delete a friend or cancel");

                // add the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                builder.setNeutralButton(" Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dataModels.get(position).setEnabled(false);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });



    }


    public void displayFriendList() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            DataModel dataModel=new DataModel();
            dataModel.setData(i+"data");
            dataModels.add(dataModel);
        }
         adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dataModels);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for this but this does not quite work correctly 
i followed your code but the output does not list the friends from the database 

my list view contains " com.example.assignment1.DataModel@2d0a62a"

Comment: Hey you need to understand how things work and modify your code as per your need. Don’t look for exact solution from someone if you want to learn follow the concept and implement in your Own way.